How to add duct to return
Currently renovating 1920 house. Took down this wall and noticed this was or is the supply return for upstairs. What bothers me is there’s no duct connecting to the vent. I do feel air being sucked down below. How would I go about fixing this?


What is the space the photo is taken from?

Tbh… I don’t know. I replacing the ceiling with drywall because I removed knob and tube and plaster ceiling. I noticed this and wondered why this was covered up like this. It seems the previous owner tried to make a second return vent for upstairs and didn’t know what he was doing and quit. There is a return duct ran at the bottom of the cavity that sucks air.In also have another return as well that is on the 1st floor. I guess my question is can I use flex duct to an 10x4 ceiling registers to connect to bottom return?

Wait, who took this photo, if not you?
